# Can tags be placed on the left and right margins of the same equation

Tags: positioning, tag

I am using AMSMath, and would like to have both a left and a right tag on the SAME equation, such as:

[L] (tag on left)     Equation (centered as normal)      (eqn number) (on right as normal)

Any suggestions as to how this can be implemented?

Comment: It can be done using flalign, sort of.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248272/how-to-mark-equation-number-but-not-change-the-reference-text/248287?s=1|0.1008#248287