# Add caption to equation/align environment

Tags: equations, environments

I try to define an environment with the same behavior as `equation`, but with an positional argument, defining a caption to the equation and is printed below the equation as shown  in the example. The requirements are

- Keep correct equation numbering
- Keep spacing behavior above and below the equation similar to the one from the `equation` environment
- (optional) Define a similar environment for the `align` environment

Currently, I'm struggling in wrapping this into an environment, can anybody help me here?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation}
        E = mc^2
    \end{equation}
    \lipsum[2]
    %-- begin capeq environment --%
    %-- positional argument: <caption> --%
    \newline
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \begin{equation*}
            E = mc^2
        \end{equation*}
        \vspace{-1cm}
        \begin{flushright}
            {\small\emph{Special-relativity equation}} (2)
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{0.05cm}
    \newline
    %-- end capeq environment --%
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: flalign gives you access to the far left and far right.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248272/how-to-mark-equation-number-but-not-change-the-reference-text